# Inner class in ES6 takes more memory?

Tags: javascript

If I create a inner class in a constructor, does it allocate memeory for each instance of the outer class that I create? For example,

```
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(maxSize) {
    // Set default max size if not provided
    if (isNaN(maxSize)) {
      maxSize = 10;
    }
    this.maxSize = maxSize;

    // Init an array that'll contain the queue values.
    this.container = [];

    // Create an inner class that we'll use to create new nodes in the queue
    // Each element has some data and a priority
    this.Element = class {
      constructor(data, priority) {
        this.data = data;
        this.priority = priority;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Does the Element class gets created for each instance of the Priority Queue class? Is there a way to make this class static?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the `Element` class to be in the prototype of the `PriorityQueue`? It can not reference the objects instantiated by the `PriorityQueue` by the `this` keyword anyway. A stand alone class might as well do the same job.

Comment: @Redu I don't specifically need `Element` class to be in prototype, but I prefer having a named class that I can without having it lie around. As for creating a separate class with no association, I think that's a bad idea since `Element` is pretty specific to `PriorityQueue` and should be contained in it as it won't be used anywhere else. One solution could be wrapping these up in an IIFE and return `PriorityQueue` so that it doesn't pollute the namespace, I think that would be a good solution. Or if I use ES6 modules, just export `PriorityQueue` from the module.

Comment: Agreed.. another method would be to define `Element` class as a static method of the `PriorityQueue` class. See extension to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're creating and assigning the class to `this.Element` inside the constructor, and the constructor runs every time `PriorityQueue` is instantiated - yes, you are creating new `Class`es for every instance. If you only want one Class for all instantiations, put it on the prototype:

```js
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(maxSize) {
    // Set default max size if not provided
    if (isNaN(maxSize)) {
      maxSize = 10;
    }
    this.maxSize = maxSize;

    // Init an array that'll contain the queue values.
    this.container = [];
  }
}
PriorityQueue.prototype.Element = class {
  constructor(data, priority) {
    this.data = data;
    this.priority = priority;
  }
}

const p1 = new PriorityQueue(1);
const p2 = new PriorityQueue(2);
console.log(p1.Element === p2.Element);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does the Element class gets created for each instance of the Priority Queue class?

Yes, kind of. It wont create a completely new class, just a closure for the class constructor function. The impact on memory will be really small, but maybe noticible when creating a few thousand priority queues.

Answer (score 1):

The methods at the prototype of the constructor function have the privilege to access the instantiated objects by the `this` keyword. But as it is done you can not use this privilege. Guessing from your question, you probably need a functionality as follows;

```js
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize || 10;

    // Init an array that'll contain the queue values.
    this.container = [];
  }
  
    // Create an inner class that we'll use to create new nodes in the queue
    // Each element has some data and a priority
  enqueueNode(data,priority){
    class Element {
      constructor(data, priority) {
        this.data = data;
        this.priority = priority;
      }
    };
    
    return this.container.length < this.maxSize ? (this.container.push(new Element(data,priority)),
                                                   this.container.sort((a,b) => a.priority - b.priority),
                                                   true)
                                                : false;
  }
}

var p1 = new PriorityQueue();
p1.enqueueNode("test",3);
p1.enqueueNode("best",1)
console.log(p1.container);
```

The `.sort()` part could perhaps be implemented more efficiently but for the sake of staying within the context of the question i use `.sort()`. Also this code is not efficient since we also define the Element class over and over for each node instantiated. As i mention in my comment it would be better to define the Element class standalone.

```js
class Element {
  constructor(data, priority){
    this.data = data;
    this.priority = priority;
  }
}

class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize || 10;

    // Init an array that'll contain the queue values.
    this.container = [];
  }
  
    // Create an inner class that we'll use to create new nodes in the queue
    // Each element has some data and a priority
  enqueueNode(data,priority){
    
    return this.container.length < this.maxSize ? (this.container.push(new Element(data,priority)),
                                                   this.container.sort((a,b) => a.priority - b.priority),
                                                   true)
                                                : false;
  }
}

var p1 = new PriorityQueue();
p1.enqueueNode("test",3);
p1.enqueueNode("best",1)
console.log(p1.container);
```

OK... the `Element` class is only needed by the objects which are instances of `PriorityQueue` so you don't want it to hang around like a stray dog. Ok then i suppose it's best to make it a static function of `PriorityQueue`. We then invoke it like `new PriorityQueue.Element(data,priority)` which is also very descriptive.

```js
class PriorityQueue {
  constructor(maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize || 10;

    // Init an array that'll contain the queue values.
    this.container = [];
  }
  
    // Create an inner class that we'll use to create new nodes in the queue
    // Each element has some data and a priority
  enqueueNode(data,priority){
    
    return this.container.length < this.maxSize ? (this.container.push(new PriorityQueue.Element(data,priority)),
                                                   this.container.sort((a,b) => a.priority - b.priority),
                                                   true)
                                                : false;
  }
}

PriorityQueue.Element = class Element {
                          constructor(data, priority){
                            this.data = data;
                            this.priority = priority;
                          }
                        };

var p1 = new PriorityQueue();
p1.enqueueNode("test",3);
p1.enqueueNode("best",1)
console.log(p1.container);
```